# React Native: The development server return response error code 500 about App.js import path for Android but not iOS

Tags: android, ios, react-native, import

I just want to move App.js into "src" folder that I created but I having issue by doing that. It is broken in Android but it is working in iOS

```
import { AppRegistry } from "react-native";
import App from "./src/App";
import { name as appName } from "./app.json";

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

[image]

I had double checked the file path is correct and it is working in iOS as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: restart your metro builder when you switch android/ios vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

After posting this question, I experiment it around by putting back the App.js to its original place and realise the android emulator still have the same reported error.

So I restart the emulator and it is had resolved.

It seems only one platform either android or iOS able to update the new import path while the another will show error code 500.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same error.

Solution:
Close the node window, this will stop the android.
run "react-native run-android" as done earlier.

This worked for me.